# alloca() with VLAs and C++

Tags: c++, c++17, alloca

The only `alloca()` replacement for C++ I have found on the Internet looks something like this:

```
template <typename F>
void alloca_(::std::size_t const n, F&& f) noexcept(noexcept(f({})))
{
  alignas(::std::max_align_t) char p[n];

  f(p);
}
```

But, obviously, this is not the `alloca()` we know and love, it is not a function, nor a macro. Can an `alloca()` implementation that resembles the `alloca()` function call semantics more closely, be written? Perhaps as a macro? Whether macro or function, it should allocate space from the stack, not the heap.

Comment: I don't follow your question. Are you looking for a replacement for stack based allocator ?

Comment: No, just something similar to alloca(), with the funcion call semantics, not like the example, that requires a functor.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the actual `alloca` that prevents you from using it in C++ code? That's one of the selling points of C++: it can natively interface with C.

Comment: Sometimes alloca() is not available.

Comment: The example doesn't require a functor... Are you saying you want something you can call like `alloca(size, foo);` given `void foo(char* memory);`? That should work as is.

Comment: No, I'd like to see an alloc() reimplementation example with vla, if it is possible.